# Samba Password must change after first logon

Tags: samba

How to enable "samba password must change after first/next logon"? I enabled a function in pdbedit file but is not working.

```
root#/opt/samba/bin/pdbedit -P "user must logon to change password" 
account policy "user must logon to change password" description: Force Users to logon for password change (default: 0 => off, 2 => on) 
account policy "user must logon to change password" value is: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command will set user to change the password at next logon,

```
net sam set pwdmustchangenow username yes
```

To verify enter the below command and check "Password must change: 0"

```
pdbedit -L -v -u username
```